# If spice is necessary for space travel, how did humans get to Arrakis in the first place?

Tags: dune

Self explanatory:

In Dune, a central point is that the guild needs the spice melange for space travel.

So how did humans get to Arrakis/Dune in the first place then?

Comment: We need engines to cross the Atlantic, so how did Europeans get to the Americas before engines were invented? The answer, of course, is that there were older slower methods that aren’t used any more except for recreation and historical re-enactment.

Comment: See also [Did the big smuggling outfits operate interstellar vessels that were not controlled by the Spacing Guild?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182926/did-the-big-smuggling-outfits-operate-interstellar-vessels-that-were-not-control)